# Time complexity for trapping rain water

Tags: python, c++, arrays, algorithm, big-o

I have been looking at different algorithms for the [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/trapping-rain-water/description/) on Leetcode beginning with [approach 1](https://leetcode.com/articles/trapping-rain-water/?page=1). The problem requires one to calculate the total water area (column width = 1) if the array values were heights of walls.

The first approach finds the minimum height of the maximum wall heights of the left and right sides of each column and adds water to the top of the given column if the column height is less than the minimum. The minimum is taken as this is the highest the water collected can reach. To calculate the maximums of each side requires making `n-1` traversals for both left and right.

I code in Python but here's the code in C++ as per the solution given on [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/articles/trapping-rain-water/?page=1). The problem is not understanding C++ but the math that is explained after the code.

```
int trap(vector<int>& height)
{
    int ans = 0;
    int size = height.size();
    for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++) {
        int max_left = 0, max_right = 0;
        for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--) { //Search the left part for max bar size
            max_left = max(max_left, height[j]);
        }
        for (int j = i; j < size; j++) { //Search the right part for max bar size
            max_right = max(max_right, height[j]);
        }
        ans += min(max_left, max_right) - height[i];
    }
    return ans;
}
```

What I don't get is how they arrived at time complexity O(n^2). I got O(n^3).

```
Index | Comparisons/Traversals
-------------------------------
  1   |            n
  2   |            n
  3   |            n
  4   |            n
  .   |            .
  .   |            .
  .   |            .
 n-1  |            n
```

The total operations performed here would be:
n + 2n + 3n + 4n + n(n-1) + n^2

Now using the arithmetic series formula
`Sum = n * (a_1 + a_n)/2` obtained [here](http://www.mathwords.com/a/arithmetic_series.htm) and pasted below
[image: Arithmetic series formulas]

The sum above would end up being:

```
Sum = n * [n + n(n-1)]/ 2 = n * [n + n^2- n)]/ 2 = (n^3)/2
```

which would give `O(n^3)`.

What am I getting wrong in my reasoning? It seems to be O(n^2) as [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trapping-rain-water/) also points it out as such.

Comment: How did you get `n + 2n + 3n + … n^2` for the total operations? You have a table of `n` entries, each of which has `n` Comparisons/Traversals, not `n, 2n, 3n, …` traversals. So it seems like it's just `n + n + n + …`

Comment: Gosh, I was sitting in front of the computer for too long. I see my mistake. I realized that I was multiplying the indices by the traversals. Thanks for asking that question. Could you post an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

> The total operations performed here would be: n + 2n + 3n + 4n + n(n-1) + n^2

But each row of your table is just `n`, not `n, 2n, …, n^2`.

And from a quick glance, it's obvious that you've filled out the table correctly, too: the inner loop has `O(n)` constant-time steps.

All of the rest of the math you're doing is correct, but irrelevant. To sum up `n` copies of `n`, you just multiple `n * n`, which is of course `n^2`, not `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of this algorithm can be also, probably in an easier way, seen by just considering the fact that you have 2 nested loops. All inner operations are `O(1)` so they don't increase the complexity in anyway. Considering nested loops it is pretty obvious that the algorithm is of order `O(n^2)` because the range of the loops is `n` and the step is `1`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'atomic'?

Comment: In the sense that they don't depend on the input length anyhow. It is just `constant number` of operation.